# How to check if form textbox/input is currently being filled out html/php

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to do is check, if any forms on the page are curently being filled out before a timed refresh. At this point I have 2 forms on my page posts and post replies and dont want that to get interupted. I want to keep the page current as close to real time as possible for incomming messages feeds ect. I've tried a few ways

a:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

b:

```
 if(isset($_POST['POST'])
```

but these just check after the form is submitted.

Comment: Javascript is ideal for this (I know you haven't tagged it)  - listen for changes on the input fields and if they are changing, don't do anything - set timeInterval will help with that

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Javascript in this site if I can!

Comment: You can't avoid Javascript for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check form field is filled before submit, it can be done by using ajax or jquery. But jquery is more faster option to have this. Remember that , user can easily false script on run time so for better practice use both validations. For jquery simple use if($('selector').val()!=""){$('form').submit();}

Answer (score 0):

***First things first-*** PHP and HTML5 are not going to help you to get real-time data. You need javascript.

Since your question is too broad, I'd suggest you to get your hands dirty with javascript first. And then get back to your original project. Good luck!

There are far too many ways to solve your problem. It depends how much you can take and what way suits best for your website.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all of your time. javascript it is?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to fix this, you can't get this done in php.

Don't do a timed refresh on the entire page. Only refresh parts of the page and leave the forms intact.

For instance, if you use jQuery, use .load() into a div with a timeout to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

**It's certainly client based job i.e JavaScript (JQuery) you can't do it through a server based language i.e PHP..!**

You can't workout anything with PHP without hyperlinks but for some instance you can workout some stuffs with use of Ajax i.e to check if current filled input data is already present in the database without submitting the form manually everytime when you stop typing it will check database for the entered data...!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I would like to say thanks again! I was trying to avoid javascript so I could better absorb html and php but it seems like javascript is a necessity esspecially in the social networking type site that I had to do for my first web design project. I spent most of the day going over javascript syntax and functions and for my issue of checking if a textbox is empty I just made a simple function
html:

```
    <textarea id= 'icon' name = 'post_' placeholder='Make a post'wrap='hard'spellcheck='true' lang='en' style='background-image:url($ico); resize: none;padding-left: 55px' required title='Make a post.' onmouseleave='CheckInput(this);'></textarea>
```

javascript:

```
    <script>
    function CheckInput(input) 
    {
        if (input.value == '') 
        {
            alert("no input");
            return false;
        }
        alert("yes input");
        return true;
    }
    </script>
```